# How to obtain a live route on a carto map?

Tags: postgis, carto, mapping, route, st-makeline

My main goal is to build an app that send lat lon from my smartphone to my carto (postgis) database and show the route "live" (in real time) as a line and not as a lot of points.

i am able to save every 40 seconds lat and long in the database as point using SQL API

example:

```
Cartourl/user/myusername/api/v2/sql?q=INSERT INTO my_table (description, the_geom) VALUES ('myroute', ST_SetSRID(ST_Point(lat, lng),4326))&api_key=myapykey
```

now i think i have to use **ST_MakeLine** to obtain a line from points.
but can i do this every time that i submit a point? has to be done before?
which query i have to use?

or i can do something like:

```
Cartourl/user/myusername/api/v2/sql?q=INSERT INTO my_table (description, the_geom) VALUES ('myroute', ST_SetSRID(ST_MakeLine(lat, lng),4326))&api_key=myapykey
```

or

```
SELECT
  ST_MakeLine(the_geom_webmercator ORDER BY ST_X(the_geom), ST_Y(the_geom) ASC) as the_geom_webmercator,
  min(cartodb_id) as cartodb_id
FROM
  my_table
```

Comment: Is it enabled as default in carto instances installed on own server? Or can you link me how to enable it?

Comment: No idea. But the routing functions are based on API calls to HERE or other routing services. So you should definetely have a provider account and API key.

Comment: Thanks! i setted in config.yml my api key of here. But seems not enabled!

Comment: Ramiro i tryed to reproduce your example: on glitch.com/edit/#!/line-points?path=index.html connecting to my own server but something fails! i cannot see the lines!!